# I am with them in Paris/ I am in Paris with them

Tags: difference, word-order, prepositional-phrases

Is there any difference between

> I am with them in Paris

and

> I am in Paris with them.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences have identical meanings. One could perhaps argue that the first phrasing puts more emphasis on the people than the place (since you lead with "I am with them"), and vice versa for the latter (since you lead with "I am in Paris"), but either one expresses the same overall idea. Any shades of implied emphasis here are very, very minor.